# Show that a basis is orthonormal

Tags: homework-and-exercises

My problem is to show that the basis $\vec{e}_n=\sqrt \frac{2}{L}\text{sin}\left(\frac{n \pi x}{L}\right)$ is orthonormal over the interval $0$ to $L$; i.e. $\langle \vec{e}_n, \vec{e}_m \rangle=1 \text{ if } n=m, \text{ and } 0 \text{ if } n \neq m$. So here's my work so far:

$\langle \vec{e}_n, \vec{e}_m \rangle = \frac{2}{L} \int_{0}^{L}\text{sin}\frac{n \pi x}{L}\text{sin}\frac{m \pi x}{L}dx=\frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^{L}\text{cos}\frac{(n-m) \pi x}{L}-\text{cos}\frac{(n+m)\pi x}{L}dx=\frac{1}{L} \left [\frac{L\text{sin}\frac{(n-m) \pi x}{L}}{(n-m) \pi}-\frac{L\text{sin}\frac{(n+m) \pi x}{L}}{(n+m) \pi}   \right ]_{0}^{L}=\frac{1}{L} \left [ \frac{L\text{sin}(n-m)\pi}{(n-m)\pi}-\frac{L\text{sin}(n+m)\pi}{(n+m)\pi}    \right ]    .$

I am making the assumption that $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ (since this has been the case with every other Fourier series basis problem I've encountered so far), although it isn't explicitly stated in the problem.

So $\langle \vec{e}_n, \vec{e}_m \rangle=0 $ for $n \neq m$ , because $\text{sin}\{(n \pm m)\pi\}=0 \text{   }\forall n,m$. But $\langle \vec{e}_n, \vec{e}_m \rangle=0 \neq 1 $ for $n=m$, because $\text{sin}\{(n-m)\pi\}=\text{sin}0=0$, and $\text{sin}\{(n+m)\pi\}=\text{sin}(2n\pi)=0.$ I'm not sure how to show that this basis is normalised.

Answer (score 0):

First off, let's be clear that there *must* be a mistake, because the integral of the square of a function can't give zero unless the function itself is zero, which here it is not.

The solution is simple: when $n=m$ your expression is undefined because of the $n-m$ in the denominator, so you should do that case separately. Or you could take the limit $n \to m$ and you would get the right answer, but good luck justifying that mathematically.

Comment: Right you are. So how would you go about this problem then?

Comment: @J.Hunt Well, I just told you. Do the $n=m$ case separately.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}\text{sin}^2\frac{n \pi x}{L} dx=\frac{2}{L}\left[\frac{L}{4}\left(2-\frac{\text{sin}(2\pi n)}{n\pi}\right )\right]=\frac{2}{L}\left(\frac{L}{2}-0\right)=1. $